# StackOverflow Stats on User Login Service Preference?

Tags: discussion, openid, authentication

StackOverflow is one of the largest companies that I know of that doesn't have its own login system but leverages OpenID and OAuth providers.  I love that idea.

My question is, would you guys be willing to release some of your data on what login services are the most popular?  This would be a very powerful set of stats as it would allow us to implement a similar login system  using only the most popular, and it would allow us to tell our clients "these are the services you want" :).

Thanks for letting me know,
Lance

Comment: I am not sure how you think it uses OAuth providers? (Surely there is some overlap in what providers offer, but I think Stack Overflow only uses the OpenID part if providers don't have a clear separation between OpenID and OAuth?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already done here

[What OpenID providers should we feature on the /login page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31021/what-openid-providers-should-we-feature-on-the-login-page)

http://img134.imageshack.us/img134/6807/stackoverflowopenidgrap.png

Comment: exactly what i was looking for... so great!  thanks

Answer (score 2):

This year old article is stating some statistics about federated identity usage on a few sites including Stackoverflow.

Quoting from link: http://social.venturebeat.com/2009/04/14/single-sign-on-service-openid-getting-more-usage/

> Sulit.com.ph (a Filipino e-commerce
>   site): 15% of new registrations are
>   via OpenID, up from 10% a couple of
>   months ago
>
> 37 Signals: 15% of logins are via
>   OpenID on their Basecamp productivity
>   application
>
> Mixx: UI improvement resulted in
>   ten-fold increase in registrations via
>   OpenID and third-party services. 20%
>   increase in registrations from direct
>   and referrer traffic.
>
> AFI (Rock band, event promotion): “We
>   were blown away with the fan response.
>   In two weeks we received 850 (YouTube
>   video) submissions, had 12,500+ fans
>   register on the website, 10,000+
>   comments, and over 100,000 votes to
>   select our winners.”
>
> Get Satisfaction: Deployments for
>   their customers — Twitter and Songbird
>   — are seeing OpenID utilization of 20%
>   or more
>
> Sourceforge.net: OpenID login has
>   grown to about 10% of total logins
>
> Stackoverflow: Third-party
>   registrations have grown from 10,000
>   to 50,000 users in a couple of months