# When accounts are associated, why is the alternative openid not copied?

Tags: discussion, openid, association, profile-copying

I've found the similar question [“Copy Profile From Stack Overflow” didn't copy alternate OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/copy-profile-from-stack-overflow-didnt-copy-alternate-openid) from July 2009, but there is no reason given, just stated that *we don't do it*.

In some answers was a mention to the problem with Google openids, but this problem has [gone](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/google-offers-named-openids/) for more than a year now.

Are there reasons (security, privacy?) that the alternative openid isn't copied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our [most common OpenId provider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31021/what-openid-providers-should-we-feature-on-the-login-page)* is Google/Gmail (not Google Profile, unfortunately).

Google OpenIds actually [vary per-domain](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/googles-openids-are-unique-per-domain/), meaning we can't meaningfully copy them between sites.

Thus, anything that copied OpenIds between accounts would be either broken or non-functional for the majority of our users.  Not worth doing, in my opinion.

<sub>*This data is a bit old, but nothing truly radical has changed.</sub>

Comment: Google/Gmail is the easy option.  It is in the first spot on the login page, and doesn't require you to type anything in.  Even if you swapped the position with the Google Profile button, that still requires the additional step of typing in the username.

Comment: I see now. I was surprised/disappointed that the big Google button on the login page wasn't the right choice for my Google profile or gave me at least the option. What's the breakdown among the two Google options for Gmail and Profile? In the link you gave there's just the cumulated entry.

Comment: @pesche - Gmail (generic Google accounts) are more than 50x more common than Google Profile accounts.  More people use Facebook, in fact (Facebook login has been supported for < 6 months; Google Profile for > 1 year).  The trick (I think) is that everyone already has a Gmail account, but few people have a Profile one.

Answer (score 2):

There's a "Copy {Site} login credentials to all Stack Exchange accounts" button on the **account tab** of your user page now:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... so given Kevin's answer, how does this work with Google OpenIds?

Comment: @jon it works, because email addresses are whitelisted and unique. Google is a mail provider, after all..