# Stats on log in options

Tags: discussion, login

Has information on the popularity of the various log in methods ever been made public? With over a dozen different ways to log in to the various stackexchange sites (Google, FB, Yahoo, WordPress etc.), I was curious what the breakdown was for each of the different methods (most/least popular etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been [discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31021/what-openid-providers-should-we-feature-on-the-login-page), though it's been a while since a proper update.

Things have gotten a little more complex as we no longer restrict users to 2 OpenIds*, so remember that when reading these stats.  We've also switched from recommending MyOpenID to user's without existing OpenIDs to our own [OpenID Provider](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/).

For all credentials in the network (with at least 100 instances):

```
OpenId                Total
-----------------   -------
google.com          833,278
stackexchange.com   228,721
facebook.com        194,253
myopenid.com        115,341
yahoo.com            90,888
launchpad.net         6,623
blogspot.com          4,047
claimid.com           3,659
wordpress.com         3,298
livejournal.com       2,255
openid.aol            2,162
steamcommunity.com      524
flickr.com              513
openid.org              465
myvidoop.com            314
appspot.com             306
technorati.com          179
mozilla.com             175
clavid.com              139
clickpass.com           127
getopenid.com           126
startssl.com            120
yandex.ru               113
```

All credentials used** in the last 30 days (with at least 100 instances):

```
OpenId               Total
-----------------  -------
google.com         249,197
stackexchange.com   79,249
facebook.com        41,822
yahoo.com           23,959
myopenid.com        14,021
launchpad.net        1,433
wordpress.com          612
claimid.com            445
openid.aol             328
blogspot.com           277
livejournal.com        225
op.demo                133
flickr.com             127
```

Although some of the other providers have shifted around a bit, what was true 3 years ago is still true now.  Google is used by a strict majority of users (~61% in the last 30 days).

<sub>*Actually the old system was even wonkier, as you could have essentially as many credentials as you wanted *provided* that one was held in common across all your different Stack Exchange user accounts.  The original system wasn't designed for the number of sites we now have.</sub>

<sub>**Our sessions are quite long lived, so logging in and out are actually kind of rare unless you're regularly changing machines.</sub>

Comment: Cool, thanks for the fast response.