# What's the breakdown of logins used on the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: discussion, openid, login

Since people ask this occasionally, I'm posting an updated breakdown of the login providers that are typically used on the Stack Exchange network.

For related historical discussion, [see this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31021/what-openid-providers-should-we-feature-on-the-login-page).

Answer (score 20):

Logins used on the Stack Exchange network (excepting Careers Stack Overflow) in the last 180 days (as of 2013-03-05):

```
Google          389,341
Stack Exchange  105,598
Facebook         65,854
Yahoo            25,223
MyOpenID         14,950
Other             3,648
Launchpad         1,842
Verisign            718
Wordpress           671
ClaimId             471
Blogspot            397
Live Journal        386
AOL                 296
```

A login is only counted once, even if it is used multiple times in that period.  The same user using different login providers will be counted multiple times (once for each distinct login credential they used).

[image]

<sub>Other in this graph includes Launchpad, Verisign, Wordpress, ClaimId, Blogspot, Live Journal, and AOL in addition to the Other group.</sub>

Surprisingly static all things considered.  Google is still (and has always been) our dominate log in provider, having actually gained a little ground in the last few years.

MyOpenID is waning, as we've replaced them as our default recommendation for new users.  Our own provider seems to have replaced them mostly, with Facebook edging out Yahoo.

Comment: Interesting that less than a year later, two of them are defunct (ClaimID and MyOpenID have been extremely problematic).