# Symantec's Personal Identity Portal (PIP) login route will be removed soon

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, openid

In the Stack Exchange routine to add a new login, the Verisign option is prominent.

If (as some users have observed) the *Personal Identity Portal* service will be discontinued in less than four months, then:

- Stack Exchange should cease promotion of the Verisign option.

Here is the notification received by me:

> **Personal Identity Portal**
>
> PIP User,
>
> This is to inform you that effective Monday 12 September 2016, Symantec will be discontinuing the service currently located at:
>
> https://pip.verisignlabs.com/
>
> All content from the service will be discarded and there will be no backups made. It is the user's responsibility to remove any content as after the date above it will not be recoverable.
>
> This will be the only notification provided. Due to the nature of the service, there is no migration plan available.
>
> If you have any questions you can send an email to:
>
> support@verisignlabs.com
>
> Thank you.

Other observations on the notice of discontinuation:

- https://indy.im/notice/19652502 (2016-05-06)
- http://pastebin.com/JHi5AXR1 (2016-05-06)
- [Symantec PIP stops 12 September 2016 - Bende / 353 - PodcastPlayer Forum](http://podcastplayer.com/t/symantec-pip-stops-12-september-2016/1268) (2016-05-07)
- [Is Symantec failing hard at being Google? - What the Daily WTF?](https://what.thedailywtf.com/topic/19880/is-symantec-failing-hard-at-being-google) (2016-05-07)
- https://twitter.com/ryan_fung/status/729563772914835456 (2016-05-09)

Comment: A May 2016 Verisign blog post: [We Need You: Industry Collaboration to Improve Registration Data Services | Between the Dots](http://blogs.verisign.com/blog/entry/we_need_you_industry_collaboration) – "… Verisign Labs launched an experimental service in February 2016, to demonstrate the viability of a federated authentication system for RDAP based on a protocol called OpenID Connect. OpenID Connect is built on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol. The approach Verisign is taking is documented in an Internet-Draft document …".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We notified users who had Verisign as their only login credential of the impending shutdown a while back.

Now that September 12 has come and gone, I pushed a change to remove it from all login and sign up screens, as well exclude it from showing up in account recovery emails.

Another provider bites the dust.

Comment: So what happens to users who had it as their only login and didn't change? They can't login to Stack Exchange anymore?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Here's hoping they at least had an email on file with us so they can go through account recovery.

Comment: @AdamLear I never had an email on file, so.... it appears this account is lost: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286924/unable-to-sign-in-with-verisign-since-it-was-discontinued-cant-access-original