# WordPress.com button is going away from login/signup screens

Tags: discussion, status-completed, login, openid

**If you are not currently using WordPress credentials to sign in, you can safely ignore this post. Otherwise, read on...**

[Wordpress.com has retired OpenID support for blogs created after January 2, 2016](https://en.support.wordpress.com/settings/openid/). Blogs created before then should still be usable as OpenID credentials, but even then, the support has been getting more and more brittle over the years. In particular, if you have a custom domain for your wordpress.com blog, you can't use that blog to sign in to Stack Exchange. Why? Not entirely sure, to be honest. There's a redirect somewhere that's busted, and as far as I can tell the issue isn't on our end at this point.

With this in mind, we're removing the WordPress button from the login and signup UI to avoid even implying that WordPress is a viable option for signing in if you haven't already:

> [image]

**If you are currently able to log in using WordPress credentials, *they will continue to work*** for as long as WordPress supports them. To log in with your existing WordPress credentials, enter your blog URL into the [freeform OpenID field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2jGy.png). I strongly encourage you to consider adding [another credential](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials) as a backup option as well, or at least make sure you have a valid email set in your profile to enable account recovery.

These changes took effect on Monday, November 21, 2016, and are now live.

Comment: Are people actually using that? Can you share some statistics?

Comment: @PatrickHofman About 2000 or so network-wide who have nothing but WP creds and at least one Q&A profile. "Using" is a broad term, though. Most people kite the same session for years, so we can't quite skip the announcement just in case, and we get the occasional bug report.

Comment: And those are active users? Or just all that happen to have an account? Also, can't you send them a mail or private message? (Or do you do that too?)

Comment: @PatrickHofman An inbox notification to affected users linking to this post is gonna go out some time tomorrow.

Comment: @PatrickHofman "All that happen to have an account". I actually need to modify my query some to pull up people whose *most recently used* credential is a Wordpress blog. That'll still have some inactive accounts, but will also catch anyone (or noone :)) who added the credential recently and intended for it to be their primary.

Comment: Thanks WP, it *finally* had to go. I hope OpenID gets expired sometime, it's too unsafe.

Comment: _"These changes will go into effect on Monday of next week, November 21."_ So, half a working day? 28 days' notice would be better, so that people have a chance to see this notice and add new credentials. Or am I missing something?

Comment: As there’s now one space free … can the Stack Exchange OpenID button come back?

Comment: questions about wordpress are off-topic for MSE, voting to close ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you will still be able to log in with the credentials using the freeform field.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: I was, for the longest time. But not anymore, for reasons similar to, but not quite the same, as described here.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Would you mind giving me a pointer to the types of security concerns that exist with OpenID? I'd like to know about that. (If not, I'll take a look for myself later when I have time.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks I think that if you change your OpenID and someone else joins with your previous OpenID then they will have access to your personal data you stored there.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion - I provide OpenIDs here on my website (https://quickmediasolutions.com/openid) for anyone that needs an extra login.

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks for the inbox notification for affected users. That was a really nice thing to do. I think that as I have a backup login set up, and as the Wordpress login will continue to work for the immediate future until Wordpress stops supporting it, there is no action I need to take right now, but I appreciate being informed about this change, thank you.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I -am- using that! I use my personal blog to distant this account from professional work. I'm just not too keen of seeing someone I know recognizes me in SO.

Comment: well, the only open source ID is gone. Hi Facebook and Google, you're my masters and I belong to you. Whatever I do is free for you to do whatever you want, dear binary god

Comment: I think an email should be sent, in addition to the inbox notification. I know that emails are evil, but not being able to log would be a major breakage of the user experience.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm If this were a "you won't be able to log in at all" case, I'd agree. However, the currently working WordPress credentials will continue to work. This is more a UI change on our end than a deprecation, so I feel an email is excessive in this case.

Comment: I like that LiveJournal is still an option :) I wonder if that's still widely used.

Comment: @devin Disappointing, I agree, but you could always do what I did when Janrain shuttered their free Open ID provider and [host your own](http://simpleid.koinic.net/).

Comment: Removing even the other login buttons should not be even a big issue, if those weren't there, we would be using the OpenID textbox all the time. Also consideration is fine as long it benefits a standard measured upon the perforamnce and usage of a feature.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit took up your concerns in my answer

Comment: @MarcusMüller: thx

Comment: for those asking: yes, I use it. thanks for inbox notification, though cut-off date does not seem to apply to my login (hopefully)

Comment: I created my stackoverflow account using Wordpress open ID. Didn't need to change it. So I'm the one you are looking for :)

Comment: @Devin I **never** use Facebook or Google credentials to login elsewhere, including here. (But, I'll bet WordPress stopped supporting their OpenID gateway because it's not tied to their revenue. *shrug*)

Comment: @jpaugh , I don't know how Open ID connects to WP revenue, and as much as I thnk about it, can't imagine a suitable scenario. The fact is that Open ID was the only available option based on free source, just that. I'm not THAT naive to believe SE doesn't do things based on THEIR revenue (as in...... ABSOLUTELY EVERYTHING). I'm just one of those creeps that supports open source

Comment: @Devin IDK why you call me a creep for supporting open source! ;-) (Although I didn't mention it.). OpenID is still available (for WP, and arbitrary other providers), and, at one point, Google's single-sign-on auth was based on OpenID, so I guess I don't understand your original comment.

Comment: @jpaugh ha ha, just exercising my right to rant while it's still free ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman wordpress login since 2008 here

Comment: @Devin What are you talking about? StackExchange still supports any arbitrary OpenID to log in, including wordpress.com which continues to work and which I continue to use. They just removed the button from the UI and making you type the full address, because the status of continuing support is unclear from wordpress.com's side. Whatever makes you say you need to log in with Facebook and Google now, or "the only open source ID is gone" or calling this an issue about open source?

Comment: (Former) WordPress OpenID user here. If you want to add a regular Stack Exchange OpenID to your account (aka "sign in with email"), follow these instructions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704

Answer (score 30):

Based on the reasons given, it sounds like a reasonable step to remove WordPress as a standard selection option (although with a less than optimal short notice!).

However, having to type in something manually each time will be a pain, so I would suggest that you replace the button with a "My Favorite OpenID Provider" button, which then fills in a user configurable setting.

This will make the issue of [What OpenID providers should we feature on the login page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31021/what-openid-providers-should-we-feature-on-the-login-page) much less of an issue because it would more or less only affect people using OpenID the very first time. This will benefit all non-default selection OpenID users, not just WordPress.

Logic something like the following:

```
if (login_method == openid && !user_settings.contains(favourite_openid_provider)
{
   answer = ask("Do you want to save " + sanitize(url) + " as your favorite...")
   if (answer == yes)
   {
       user_settings.save(favourite_openid_provider, url)
   }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you see that “favorite OpenID provider” setting stored? Because this is the login dialog, so you cannot have this stored in the user configuration you get access to *after* the login.

Comment: @poke Cookie? Local storage?

Comment: @D_4_ni So the same location the login session itself is stored..?

Comment: @poke Yes, but obviously with a longer lifetime, and not cleared by a logout. I don't think there are better ways to store data about the user not sitting behind the login.

Comment: @poke this can easily, but not altogether reliably, solved with JavaScript's `localStorage`.

Comment: +1 Certainly something The Powers could consider, actually, independently of the WP login button removal.

Comment: I agree it would be nice to have this saved in a long lived cookie on the client side. There should still be a way to override that stored cookie on login time. And if there is such an override, it may not even be necessary to ask at login time if the user want to save it. It ought to be safe to save it without asking the user.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` (expected a closing parentheses but found `}` instead)

Comment: @cat Please improve the answer directly instead of just adding a comment.

Comment: @hlovdal It's one character (< 6) and my comment's glib anyways since it's pseudocode...

Answer (score 5):

If you set up your account with WordPress OpenID like I did and want to create a regular Stack Exchange OpenID (a.k.a. "log in with email") for your account, follow [these directions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704).

You can also [follow these directions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials) to add another OpenID, such as Google or Facebook, to your account.

Theoretically, you can have as many OpenIDs and email logins associated with your account as you want.

Answer (score 3):

What about inferring the OpenID URL from the e-mail address itself?

When an e-mail *someone@example.com* is entered, a request to the site is made in the background to see if the page includes the required OpenID elements, and if so, allow to use it right away by clicking on the login button without filling in the OpenID URL explicitly?

That would make it a lot easier to use a custom OpenID.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you're going to type in your email, you might as well type in your OpenID? If I understand you right, this would also slow things down in most cases - where people log in with email and password - if we wait for the OpenID check. Or it'd be a usually wasted request if we don't wait. Most people don't sign in with their own custom OpenID domain. I'm also not sure that having an email address at the OpenID-providing domain is all that common?

Comment: @AdamLear this has the advantage of using a single field for both OpenID and SE account users. User types in e-mail -> check if OpenID and if so use that -> if no OID ask for password.

Answer (score 2):

I guess 2000 people discovering the button for their login method (WordPress) is gone and not knowing how to work-around that, and not knowing if that login method is just somehow no longer supported at all, could end up to be a support issue.

I'd suggest that at least for a while (indefinitely), add a note (and link) below the remaining login buttons like: "Looking for the `WordPress OpenID` login button? [Click here for the story](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287062/wordpress-com-button-is-going-away-from-login-signup-screens)".

Comment: I've "kited" my OpenID session for years it seems. I signed up for SO when it opened, and at the time my thoughts were "oh dog, not another login/password combo to keep track of", so I went with my old WP account. So no, I wouldn't have noticed for ages that the login method had disappeared, I guess until I logged in from a new computer.

Comment: Oh and thanks admins for the message in my Inbox, well played.