# After using custom domain name for WordPress, now Stack Exchange thinks I am a different user

Tags: support, openid

I use my WordPress as open id to log in to Stack Exchange.
My URL was like name.wordpress.com. I have upgraded it to use name.com.
I can still log it, but now Stack Exchange thinks I am a new user.

How can I link/merge the two accounts?

Comment: Wordpress OpenID with a custom domain doesn't work too well, see [WordPress.com button is going away from login/signup screens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287062/)