# Merge question after finding it as a duplicate- Feature request

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Hi,
What is the best practice after finding a question as a duplicate to another one?

Anyways the question will get closed eventually. But what if it was possible to merge the question to the duplicate, because the duplicate can contain valuable answers.

***Feature request:***

**Merge a duplicate question to the original one**. Voting has to be done in this case for avoiding unnecessary merge.

Comment: See [duplicate question etiquette: to delete or not to delete?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230)

Answer (score 9):

This feature already exists and is moderator only. If you believe a question should be merged, flag it for moderator attention and say what ID you think it should be merged with.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say. In this case, I just delete my question if nobody has answered it yet.

If you found a matching question, put a comment on the question itself and ask that OP to ask your things too.