# Moderators for language-specific tags?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I was just curious, does SO have moderators that mainly work specific language tags? Or do all moderators work to maintain all tags?

If not, would it be beneficial to consider electing some moderators for broad language-specific tags, such as [php](/questions/tagged/php), [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), or [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)? They could focus primarily on keeping their tag clean, although they'd still be expected to help out with other tags when they can.

I was thinking of this because I was looking through the moderator candidates and realized I don't really know any of them. I mostly look at questions in [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf), and can think of some users there who would make great moderators for that tag, but none of them are running and I have no idea if they'd even care to maintain other tags.

Comment: No, and it has been proposed before, although I don't remember if it was on MSO or in a chat room.

Comment: There was a suggestion for a [****book specific mod](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/can-we-have-a-facebook-stackoverflow-mini-site-moderator-election) - I think the same reasoning would apply for tag specific moderators...

Comment: As a non-chemist, I still got chem.SE pro-temship. I declared my lack of knowledge outright, and the community(and Aarthi) told me that subject knowledge isn't necessary for a mod. Which applies here as well. I bet Boltclock and the rest moderate your tags, you just don't notuce it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no language-specific moderators at the moment.

But I guess most of the time the moderators will probably only take (important) decisions content-related when it's a tag they are at least somewhat familiar with (unless there are other, obvious language-agnostic problems with a question, answer or comment).

I see no added benefit, since keeping a tag *clean* is something a lot of users can now already collectively aspire to via other mechanisms of the site (editing, downvoting, voting to close, flagging for moderator attention, ...).

I'd rather have all moderators be able to state their opinion / intervene then have some feel automatically excluded since another moderator (group) feels they `own` a specific tag. That would introduce an extra concept of *power*, and power tends to create opportunities for abuse imho.

Comment: You're right, I forgot moderators were only supposed to be exception handlers, and the users are the ones responsible for maintaining the site (or "their" tag) :)

Answer (score 6):

This is primarily something that the high-reputation users are responsible for. Essentially, moderators are *not* involved in deciding quality/correctness of posts. The community at-large does that with votes, votes to close, and at the higher-ends, votes to delete.

Moderators are here for things that generally don't require specific knowledge of the topics of any individual tag at all. When something comes to a mods attention, it's usually far beyond that. (it's spam, it's just a link, it's off-topic, etc)

---

Please also note awoodland's very important exception to the above, in the comment below. When merging two questions as duplicates, good knowledge of the topics involved is definitely required.

Comment: The one area where that's not the case is duplicate specific merging http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108784/vote-to-merge-feature-for-10k-20k-users