# Migrate answers to original post from exact duplicate post?

Tags: feature-request, answers, migration, duplicate-questions

I seen many duplicates that actually have useful answers and upvotes to that question. So what if, when the duplicated question becomes flagged, the answers are then automatically migrated to the original question?

For example:

### From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/duplicates/292/user32?user32:

This is how you can do it:

```
// The code
```

Comment: Your link is 404.

Comment: ...and your question appears incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for already exists: Duplicates can be merged. This moves all of the answers to one question and leaves a placeholder behind. If you find a duplicate that's a good candidate for merging by all means flag it for a moderator.

I'm against automatic merging, however. There's no guarantee that the duplicate actually does have useful answers. Further, sometimes duplicates aren't *exact* duplicates. Merging them would be a mistake.

See also: [Merge question after finding it as a duplicate- Feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7270/merge-question-after-finding-it-as-a-duplicate-feature-request)