# Close as duplicate, or leave it to assist others with weak search-fu?

Tags: discussion, search, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [duplicate question etiquette: to delete or not to delete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/duplicate-question-etiquette-to-delete-or-not-to-delete)

I posted a question that I knew was a duplicate, because I was having no luck at all searching up the question that I knew was there.

[Pre-load AD user profile to domain joined PC](https://serverfault.com/questions/67296/pre-load-ad-user-profile-to-domain-joined-pc)

Squillman was there to help me out, but I want to make the solution easier to find.  Edit it (or its tags), or leave the dupe Q up?

Comment: Do not delete it! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/duplicate-question-etiquette-to-delete-or-not-to-delete

Comment: Close it     :)

Comment: Thanks, John.  Now I've gone and doubled my search fail on meta.  ;)

Answer (score 9):

The question should be closed if its an exact duplicate, but having it posted is often a good thing. Especially because, as you suggest, it is often hard to word searches in the right way to find a question, even if you know it exists, so having more "pointers" to the canonical question is not a bad thing.

Comment: And those who close it should point to the duplicate, as usual.

Answer (score 6):

Closing doesn't stop it from being found - so long as it isn't deleted.

You might want to edit it to explain *why* you think it shouldn't be deleted.

Alternatively, you could always edit the duplicate to include the appropriate search terms there.

Answer (score 4):

> Squillman was there to help me out, but I want to make the solution easier to find. Edit it (or its tags), or leave the dupe Q up?

All of the above!

- Give the original a better title (not the same as yours) and some useful tags (the same as yours).
- Close the duplicate with a link back to the original.
- Don't delete the duplicate, so that it may act as a signpost to future searchers.

Comment: If you change the title of the original, you are limiting people who use *those* words from finding it.

Comment: @devinb: you can keep the original words and still flesh it out a bit. The original title - "Precached Windows Logins?" - is accurate but unnecessarily brief; something like, "Can I pre-cache or otherwise pre-load Windows login credentials prior to deployment?" both describes the actual question and provides more key words for searching.