# Is it appropriate to bump an old question for getting public evaluation of its tags?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, tags, bump

When preparing for a retag request, especially one that would require a merging, I think it is more comfortable to get rid of some of the outlier questions that would not match the merge. For example, [[searching]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/searching) is not really any different than [[search]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search), a good portion of the questions are tagged with both and the majority of the remnants are just dividing the exact same content into two tags. There are a couple outliers that just do not need any search-based tag, but I became confused with [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22851/close-as-duplicate-or-leave-it-to-assist-others-with-weak-search-fu-closed). Myself, I could argue both ways that the [search] tag does and does not belong. As such, I would rather get someone else's opinion, but when these situations arise there are not always retaggers in the comment/edit threads to whom I could address.

Whether I am prepping a retag-request or not, is it alright to bump these questions up to the front page? Would it be appropriate to do this on the actual Q&A sites outside of Meta, bumping a question just to get some evaluation of its tags? If it is not appropriate, what is a better course of action for getting attention to these situations when I run into them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, please don't bump the questions themselves.

Instead, ask a meta-question about what to do in a particular situation, like what I did [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50873/tag-disambiguation-request-rts-real-time-strategy-and-on-so).

There are a number of reasons for that:

- Since the number of edits made on a post pushes it towards CW, the number of edits should be kept to a minimum (common courtesy since these are other people's posts we're talking about)
- Given the previous point, if you need to get attention a *second* or subsequent time, it's not really fair to keep making dummy edits
- If there's any discussion needed, bumping a question does not allow for that to happen; and in any event, the discussion would end up in the wrong place (i.e., questions shouldn't really contain metadiscussion -- that's why Meta was set up in the first place)
- Bumping a question doesn't convey the real intent of the bump. You could add a comment in the edit summary, but most often, people don't read that for every edit made

Comment: On the last bullet point, I would leave a standard comment as well, but given all the rest of your points I understand that bumping would be bad. Also, your example also gives me a bit better relief for bringing up something like this just for a singular question. While I have your attention, though, any chance you have any input for the [dispute that inspired my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22851/close-as-duplicate-or-leave-it-to-assist-others-with-weak-search-fu-closed)? ♪

Comment: I don't have a problem leaving a search tag on that question, as she's asking about how to best let people find answers through search, essentially. (Note: retag to `[exact-duplicates]` while you're at it.) @Gra