# Is it better to delete questions that have been marked as duplicate, or should they be kept?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do not delete duplicates!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates)

When one of my questions is marked as duplicate, should I deleted it, or keep it so other users have more chances to find the correct question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do not delete duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates). After this question is closed as duplicate please delete it.

Comment: ironic that this question on duplicates has been asked twice already -- 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates & here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/duplicate-question-etiquette-to-delete-or-not-to-delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should definitely be kept (if it's not a word for word match), since duplicate questions will often have different wording than the original. This allows a question to be found in more ways through search, since the duplicate has a link to the original.

Comment: It could also help if I use different words to ask the question, or I put in evidence something that in the other question was not clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you typed in the title of your question and the original didn't come up in the search, then it's okay to keep yours around so others can find it and the link to the original.  If it's truly an exact duplicate (I've seen word-for-word title matches before) then it can be deleted.

Comment: I was thinking to questions with different titles; in the case the title is the same, then it doesn't help to find the correct question as it has the same chance to be found that the original question has.