# Why is my request to remove my own duplicate question denied?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions, moderators, self-delete

I asked several questions here at meta. Some of them were duplicates and marked as such.

I do not want to add to the cluttering, and they are downvoted (the community didn't like the questions), so I flagged them to be removed. Those request where denied.

I am wondering, what is the policy of removing questions? Why can't I remove my own question (by a moderator)?

Comment: Dupes are not always a bad thing. Stop worrying. Move on. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: @Bart: I can move on, but since they are not really appreciated (they were downvoted) I cannot imagine why anyone wants to keep them.

Comment: Because they might make good signposts to the duplicate. Or because they contain valuable answers. At most they should be merged. If not, leave them alone.

Comment: See [Do not delete duplicates!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates) or [Duplicate question etiquette: to delete or not to delete?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/duplicate-question-etiquette-to-delete-or-not-to-delete)

Comment: Also: people gave good answers to your questions. Should we take away their reputation because you asked questions that were received badly by the community?

Comment: @George+Bart: You have some good points!