# Pinging in a comment sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: discussion, support, comments, comment-replies

I have noticed that it seems to be good etiquette to write the "at" sign and then the userid of the person whose post or comment one is responding to in a comment.  I believe that's called *pinging.*  I've tried to do this and sometimes it works, and sometimes it just disappears when I hit "Enter."

Am I supposed to ping?  If so, are there some tricks to make it work more consistently?  Or could someone at least explain the pattern to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to ping the person who submitted the post you are commenting on, it will be deleted automatically as it is unnecessary. They will get a ping anyway. Similarly for those who have already commented on that post.

So save your pings for those who won't get auto-pinged.

[Useful FAQ here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/154443)

Comment: Should I delete my question?  Because it was a duplicate?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230/154443

Comment: Thank you, I'll take that as a no, and leave the question in place.